# How to save JSON data to Google Firebase's Firestore database?

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, node-request

Is it possible to save JSON data directly to Firebase Firestore?

I tried saving my below json data,

#### Data

```
[{"id":"1234","name":"Chair","symbol":"CHR"}]
```

#### Code:

```
request({url: 'https://api.example.com/v1/data', json: true}, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.send(body);    
            console.log(body);    
        }
        else {
            console.log(response.statusCode + " " + error);
        }
        db.collection('market').doc('price').set(body);

    });
```

#### Error

> Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain
>   JavaScript object.

#### Workaround

1. JSON.parse() for the body

   ```
   db.collection('market').doc('price').set(JSON.parse(body));
   ```
2. JSON.stringify() for the body

   ```
   db.collection('market')doc('price').set(JSON.stringify(body));
   ```

I am still getting error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON data is an array.  Notice that it's surrounded with square brackets:

```
[{"id":"1234","name":"Chair","symbol":"CHR"}]
```

You can't use an array as the contents of a document in Firestore.  Perhaps you just want to add the first element of the array, which is an object:

```
db.collection('market').doc('price').set(body[0]);
```

Of course, before indexing into an array, you should verify that the element exists.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I looked pretty much everywhere about this error and could not figure out why it was happening.